# Limit number of results in object.map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm importing the `spaces` object. I only want to render 3 of the `Card` components which requires attributes from `spaces`. Imagine a 'featured' section on a website displaying only a few items from a larger list.

With the below code I'm currently rendering all of the results instead of 3, am I using the correct methods? And if so, is the order wrong?

```
<div className="row">

          {spaces.map(item => {

            for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

              return (

                <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4" key={item.id}>

                  <Card
                    town={item.town}
                    name={item.name}
                    net={item.net}
                    day={item.day}
                    night={item.night}
                    dog={item.dog}
                    parking={item.parking}
                    image={item.image}
                  />

                </div>
              )
            }

          })}

</div>
```

Comment: `spaces.slice(0,3).map(...` ?

Comment: `map` goes *through the entire array* and executes the function you've given it. If you want to limit it, then either `filter` by condition or `slice` to a specific number of items.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`spaces.map` will iterate over all elements in `spaces` and produce a new array, with a new value for each existing item.

The loop inside the `map` callback is useless since you are `return`ing in the first iteration, terminating the loop immediately.

If you only want to get the first 3 spaces, then you can `.slice` the array:

```
<div className="row">
          {spaces.slice(0,3).map(item => {
              return (
                <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4" key={item.id}>
                  <Card
                    town={item.town}
                    name={item.name}
                    net={item.net}
                    day={item.day}
                    night={item.night}
                    dog={item.dog}
                    parking={item.parking}
                    image={item.image}
                  />
                </div>
              )
          })}
</div>
```

Comment: This worked a treat, thanks for the simple explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below

```html
<div className="row">

          {spaces.map((item,index) => {

              if(index < 3){
              return (

                <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4" key={item.id}>

                  <Card
                    town={item.town}
                    name={item.name}
                    net={item.net}
                    day={item.day}
                    night={item.night}
                    dog={item.dog}
                    parking={item.parking}
                    image={item.image}
                  />

                </div>
              )
            }

          })}

</div>
```

Comment: This works only because React skips over `null` and `undefined` "elements". It's not the right approach though.

Comment: if the element null or undefined then in this case, you can use counter variable increment that counter if item != null or undefined and check the counter value < 3 or not.

Comment: That's not what I meant. You are still iterating over all elements and producing an array that looks like `[element, element, element, undefined, undefined, ...]`. It works because React will ignore the `undefined` elements in this array, but the better approach is to not iterate over the whole array in the first place.

Comment: Yes, you are right thanks.